# How do I reset a transform effect in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, distort

I've been fooling around with the free distort `Effect > Distort & Transform > Free Distort` feature, and now I want to reset the shape to its normal aspects.

I was really unlucky and managed to quit the program during the progress, but managed to save the file. However, now I can't <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to bring it back to its original form.

When I use the feature again `Effect > Distort & Transform > Free Distort` the shape will go back to its original form, but as I click "OK", it will stay unchanged..

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delete the Free Distort effect from the Appearance panel and you'll be fine.

[image]